# How to connect over TCP from ionic (phonegap) to websocket on server?

Tags: go, websocket, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I have installed and running this script on server: https://github.com/gorilla/websocket
Everything was configured and running ok when I was using ios native application but now I have to switch to phonegap and I cannot find example which is working.
I cannot move to another script on my server because it would be to much work.
Is there any way that I can connect to my server from phonegap ionic?
My application is for ios and android, it's game which needs real time connection just like chat application.
Thank you

Comment: The gorilla Websocket library aims to implement the RFC6455 web socket standard. A quick search yields third party libraries for phone gap that add web socket support. https://github.com/mkuklis/phonegap-websocket

Comment: @benjic - it says it is for android only